# Swapping cells in table view section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view section with two custom cells. I want to swap the cells in that section when the some other action triggers.

[image]

The top cell should slide to the bottom, and the bottom cell should slide to the top.

My current code results in blank cells' area

[image]

when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns:

```
    // flag is set to YES when reloadSections is called 
    if (flag) {             

        if (self.currentAddressingMode == AddressingModeToSelf) {

                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    return self.outNumberCell;
                }
                else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                    return self.inNumberCell;
                }

            }
            else if (self.currentAddressingMode == AddressingModeToCounterpart) {

                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    return self.inNumberCell;
                }
                else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                    return self.outNumberCell;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: I don't sure want you want, you should just swap two object in data model (array) and do reloadData for table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this question by creating custom cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method (by adding subviews to them), instead of subclassing. For animated cell swapping I used the `UITableView`'s `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method (iOS 5 SDK). The other related methods work fine too (it depends of the swapping animation that you need). The code chunk that I posted to this question remains completely unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can return needed cells in `(UICell*) cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then `reloadSections` animated if needed.

Comment: I tried that... It didn't work as expected (the cells' area becomes blank when cellForRowAtIndexPath returns).

Comment: Yes, all cells are programmatically created, no IB/storyboards. Added a code chunk to the question.

Comment: Please specify what's 'blank'

Comment: Posted an appropriate screenshot of that area.

Comment: what about other delegate functions (like number of rows in section)?

Comment: I don't think that they matter. They doesn't do any specific work in this case. For example, numberOfRowsInSection just returns 2 for this section.

Comment: how do you create the cells for the first time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17029/discussion-between-dreamzor-and-rusmacxlam)

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to happen, you need to change the order of the data yourself in the dataSource. Then you could do reloadData like this:

[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: Currently it results in blank cells' area when method returns. Added a code chunk to the question.

Comment: Don't return anything with special cases in cellForRow... Just change the order in the dataSource, which is the array olding the data of your table, and call the method I wrote about. You cold use te same if...else... conditions while sorting and reordering your data - instead of using those same conditions in cellForRow...

Comment: These two cells are created directly in cellForRowAtIndexPath, there's no data source for them. Also, I need to preserve the text of cells' text fields while reordering. Tried to put these cells in an array and change its ordering – same problem, nothing has changed.